# Multi-value image field hangs browser on upload and remove

Tags: ajax, media

I have a content type with a multi-value image field set to unlimited.  My client finds that they cannot either remove an existing image or upload a new image to a node which about 60 images loaded because Firefox just hangs ( spinner stops moving ) and in IE it reports 'A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly'.

If I log onto as the same user it works OK for me.  Their Internet connection isn't superfast but it isn't satellite, and should be about 1MB.

Nothing is reported in the Drupal log.  Cealrly there is an issue with the AJAX update but why does it work for me and not for them ?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Elb

Comment: which Progress indicator option are you using for the image field?

Comment: The image widget uses what I'd call a spinner, but I don't think this is a configurable option ?  It's just what Drupal core does.

Comment: Well, yes you can configure it; but you need to enable **Upload progress**. Check Drupal status report `admin/reports/status`